# Create Pie Chart In Tableau using Calculated field

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, pie-chart

I have create 2 calculated fields.

Example:

1. will have remaining amount (100%)
2. will have spend amount (60%)

both of these fields are calculated with different formulas.

Now I want to use these calculated fields in pie chart where it should show spend amount and remaining amount in pie chart.

Is there any way where I can use calculated fields in pie chart.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 calculated fields are both Measures, you can drag Measure Values to the Size or Angle card and Measure Names to the Color card for your Pie chart.

You'll need to filter the Measure Names to the 2 calculated fields only.